# Comparing weighted and non-weighted anthropometric and categorical data

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, sas, weighted-sampling

I wish to do a comparative analysis between a primary, local data set and the National Health and Nutrition Examination Survey (NHANES).  Specifically, I'd like the comparison to be limited to 11 year olds (my survey was only sixth graders, hence 11 year olds) and the intent here is to compare means for four anthropmetric variables and more importantly to compare obesity prevalence based on category frequencies between the two data sets (normal, overweight, obese).

However, my dataset is unweighted (we measured at least 80% of the 6th grade population in the area), while the NHANES is weighted (its sampling design involves oversampling under-represented populations).  I have been attempting to conduct my analysis in SAS, as it is what is most recommended by the NCHS (National Center for Health Statistics) for working with the NHANES.

Any suggestions on how I should proceed from here?

Here is a link to the Continuous NHANES tutorial in case more information on the sampling design is needed: http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/tutorials/Nhanes/SurveyDesign/SampleDesign/intro.htm

Comment: "we covered at least 80% of our population of interest" I highly doubt this means what you think it means. Do you actually mean to say, of the people approached 80% were eligible or participated in the study or completed the survey?

Comment: It means we measured 80% of all sixth graders in the metropolitan area.

Answer (score 1):

The NHANES website is quite thorough. Have you adequately reviewed their examples and data descriptions? Here's an example for how they apply their survey weights:

http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/tutorials/NHANES/NHANESAnalyses/DescriptiveStatistics/Task3b.htm

In their breakdown of the `PROC SURVEYMEANS`, they show this line of code:

`weight wtmec4yr;`

with the following description

> Use the weight statement to account for the unequal probability of sampling and non-response. In this example, the MEC weight for four years of data (wtmec4yr) is used.

As you may be aware, survey weights are analytic weights intended to account for non-response and sampling strategies to reliably ascertain trends in rare populations.

Comment: I'm not having any issues applying the survey weights to the NHANES data in the standalone context, its the comparison to my unweighted data set that is problematic. Would the solution to my unweighted survey be as easy as establishing a new weight statement, say newwt=1 vs. newwt=wtmec2yr (or whatever weight I decided to use for the NHANES)?

Comment: If you have all your data, there's no need for statistical comparison. NHANES, once standardized, *is* the population data. Your data additionally *is* your population data. Therefore, there are no statistics involved (which is distilling sample estimates to a popuation). Make meaningful comparisons of population frequencies and let it be.

Answer (score 1):

a few notes about what you've described  :)

1) AdamO is correct that once you calculate the statistic of interest from the weighted NHANES data set, that's the survey's estimate of the population..and if you have a comparison statistic also at the population level, you can just say "yes" or "no" RE whether your MSA's results are inside the nhanes confidence interval.  that is: "the BMI of sixth graders in our MSA are/are not statistically significantly different from the average as computed from a nationwide sample."

here's some [easy-to-use scripts to work with nhanes in the R language](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20health%20and%20nutrition%20examination%20survey%20%28nhanes%29)

2) if BMI is your most important item, doing what you've described is much better done with the "sample child" component of the national health interview survey than with nhanes.  the two-year nhanes file has about 200 records for 11 year olds.  using the four-year weights means you've got a weird sample population of 400 11 year olds across the survey years 2007-2010.  the 2012 nhis file is already available, and has 600+ respondents who are 11 years old.

here's the [page with easy-to-use scripts to work with nhis](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20health%20interview%20survey%20%28nhis%29) ..and you specifically should modify [this script](https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd/blob/master/National%20Health%20Interview%20Survey/2011%20personsx%20plus%20samadult%20with%20multiple%20imputation%20-%20analyze.R) to work with the `samchild` (instead of `samadult`) file on the 2012 data sets.

Comment: Hi Anthony, I am revisiting this research currently and have a few concerns. I am mostly interested in comparing prevalence rates of overweight and obesity (using chi-square) between my population and the NHANES 11 year olds. Is it safe to conduct this type of analysis?

Comment: why are you using nhanes and not [nhis](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20health%20interview%20survey%20%28nhis%29) or [yrbss](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/youth%20risk%20behavior%20surveillance%20system%20%28yrbss%29) or [nsch](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20survey%20of%20children%27s%20health%20%28nsch%29)?  the confidence interval around the nhanes-based number is going to be giant because the sample size of 11 year olds in nhanes is probably `20` kids.  so no, it's not safe ;)

Comment: Well, I've appended several NHANES datasets so that the sample size for 11 year olds is comparable to mine (n=about 630). The issue with those other datasets is that they are interview-based rather than measurement-based and thus only include BMI rather than other anthropometric variables.